# MVC4 construct url with controller/parameter/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

have a look to the following URL:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/@MYCOMPANY.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/CloudServicesExtension/CloudService/**MYSERVICENAME**/dashboard

It looks like the url is in the form {controler}/ActionName/{parameter}/ActionName

How can I generate such URL in MVC4/Razor?
Indeed, I want to build url in the form:
http://www.myservice.com/Configuration/{Source or Target}/{DomainName}/{ConfigurationType}

ex:

http://www.myservice.com/Configuration/Source/mydomain.com/ConnexionConfiguration
http://www.myservice.com/Configuration/Source/mydomain.com/AttributesConfiguration

Thanks.

Comment: Just config your routing. There are tons of examples around it. Search  routing configuration in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create per action routes, for each action, or include the controller name and action name in the url and then use something like this:

routes.MapRoute("Default","{controller}/{source}/{domain}/{action}")

so a controller called Configuration with an action called Setup and a domain of example.com and source of welcome would be

/Configuration/welcome/example.com/setup